# Block style change to a form

Tags: delphi, styles, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Using Delphi 10.2.3: I have a splash screen form that's created and displayed in the app's main-form unit's initialization section.  The form contains a bitmap background with some labels on it for title, copyright, version, build date and initialization status, `ParentFont` is off for the form and the labels, and the label's font name, size and color are all set at design time to a good contrast for the bitmap background.

In the main form's constructor, the user's choice of style is read from the config and set using `TrySetStyle()`.  But this can change the font color on that splash screen form, which I don't want.  I've turned off all the `StyleElements` for both the form and the labels, but that has no effect.

How can I prevent the change of style from affecting the splash form?

Comment: Delphi 10.4 has support for per-control/form styling which would make this a lot easier.  The feature is controlled by a new StyleName property for the TControl class. For older versions try setting the StyleElements properties to false again after TrySetStyle().

Comment: As I don't have the 10.2 Tokyo version available, I tried in 10.1 Berlin. Mainform uses one of the available styles (Cyan Dusk) and for the splash screen I have unticked all `StyleElements` both for the form as well as a label. The form and the label keeps their design time formatting while the main form follows the loaded style. Obviously you do something different, but hard to tell what. Perhaps you want to prepare a [mre].